# How to check multidimensional array contains any value in it or all elements are empty in php without for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my array anyone can help would be appreciate. i want to check if array has any value on it or all values are empty. multidimensional array is dynamic either it can be index of 0 or more than 0.....n . but can this possible to check without for loop ?

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => Array
         (
             [title1] => 
             [title2] => 
             [image] => 
         )
    [1] => Array
         (
             [title1] => 
             [title2] => 
             [image] => 
         )
    [2] => Array
         (
             [title1] => SampleTitle
             [title2] => 
             [image] => 
         )
)
```

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: What do you have against loops?

Comment: No, I want to know if any solution is there using any php array function. that we can identify  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:  [source for flatten from @too much php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array).

```
$arr=Array
 (
    '0' => Array
         (
             'title1' => '',
             'title2' => '',
             'image' => ''
         ),
    '1' => Array
         (
             'title1' => '',
             'title2' => '',
             'image' => ''
         ),
    '2' => Array
         (
             'title1' => 'SampleTitle',
             'title2' => '',
             'image' => ''
         )
);

function flatten(array $array) {
    $return = array();
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });
    return $return;
}

$str=flatten($arr);
if(!array_filter($str)) {
    echo "all are null";
}else{
    echo "values are there";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$filtered = array_filter($my_array);
if (!empty($filtered)) {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what the question asked for. Should be the correct answer